# Jersey delete - id contains slashes - URLEncode not working

Tags: java, rest, jersey, urlencode, backslash

I am trying to make a Jersey DELETE. The id which needs to be deleted contains slashes.

On the client, I am using the URLEncoder to encode the string before making the call so that the URL will have the encoded string.

```
URLEncoder.encode( idToDelete, "UTF-8");
```

On the server, I am using the URLDecoder to decode the encoded string.

```
URLDecoder.decode(idToDelete, "UTF-8");
```

This is the method on the server that I am trying to access

`@DELETE
  @Path("types/{typeId}")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public ResponseEnvelope.EmptyEnvelope deleteType(@PathParam("typeId") String deleteTypeId)`

I am not sure why I am not able to hit this method. I was wondering if it has anything to do with the path param.

Could someone please suggest. Thanks in advance!